# UIViewController resizing itself between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, viewdidappear, viewwillappear

I've got a really strange bug in my project. I've got a `UIScrollView` as my main, big view.  Inside of it, I have a `UIViewController` (not `UITableViewController`) which has a `UITableView` instance variable, as well as some miscellaneous `UIButtons`. I have set the view controller's view frame to `CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 388)`, as I have a tab bar above it (this is not functional yet).  At first it works great and looks great, but once I present and dismiss a `modalViewController` (thus reloading the `UIViewController`, I believe), it pushes the `UIViewController`'s view to the top of the screen (by default setting it to `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)`, but since I've set `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `NO`, it now sets it to `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 388)`.

I've tracked this problem to somewhere between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  Here are my exact logs after dismissing the `modalViewController`:

> 2011-05-06 11:08:39.974 Campus[1570:207] Frame is 0.000000, 64.000000, 320.000000, 388.000000 (viewWillAppear)
>   2011-05-06 11:08:40.378 Campus[1570:207] Frame is 0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 388.000000 (viewDidAppear)

As you can see, the frame is fine in `viewWillAppear`, but not in `viewDidAppear`.

I've done the following things to try to fix it:
- Set the desired frame in `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear`.
- Set my `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `NO`.
- Killed my `[super viewWillAppear:]` and `[super viewDidAppear:]` calls in my method overrides.

What should I do?!?!?

Comment: Who is presenting the modal view controller?

Comment: The UIViewController that's resizing himself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem here was that, as of iOS 4, Apple only supported 1 view controller per window.  However, as of iOS 5, Apple has added support for container view controllers, and has added methods to `UIViewController` such as `addChildViewController:`.  Using the container view controller algorithm solved my problem.  Visit the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

EDIT: for those of you too lazy to search "container view controller" in the class reference, here's the gist of the related section in the class reference:

> A custom UIViewController subclass can also act as a container view
>   controller. A container view controller manages the presentation of
>   content of other view controllers it owns, also known as its child
>   view controllers. A child’s view can be presented as-is or in
>   conjunction with views owned by the container view controller.
>
> Your container view controller subclass should declare a public
>   interface to associate its children. The nature of these methods is up
>   to you and depends on the semantics of the container you are creating.
>   You need to decide how many children can be displayed by your view
>   controller at once, when those children are displayed, and where they
>   appear in your view controller’s view hierarchy. Your view controller
>   class defines what relationships, if any, are shared by the children.
>   By establishing a clean public interface for your container, you
>   ensure that children use its capabilities logically, without accessing
>   too many private details about how your container implements the
>   behavior.
>
> Your container view controller must associate a child view controller
>   with itself before adding the child’s root view to the view hierarchy.
>   This allows iOS to properly route events to child view controllers and
>   the views those controllers manage. Likewise, after it removes a
>   child’s root view from its view hierarchy, it should disconnect that
>   child view controller from itself. To make or break these
>   associations, your container calls specific methods defined by the
>   base class. These methods are not intended to be called by clients of
>   your container class; they are to be used only by your container’s
>   implementation to provide the expected containment behavior.

Comment: how can you fix this problems, can you post some example?

Comment: Please provide a code sample with the answer! Linking to the vast UIViewController Class reference doesn't help anybody else.

Comment: @TRedman My code has changed so much since a year ago that I don't think I could possibly give a useful code sample.  I've quoted part of the class reference in an edit