# Animating self.view.frame?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to mimic UINavigationController's pushViewController using UIView animation but I have seem to run into an issue. I cannot animate the self.view.frame.

This is the code I am using but self.view just won't move!

```
    [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
    [myViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480)];
                         [myViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [view1.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is that code getting called from?

Comment: Its getting called from view1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider where the views are just before the animations start:

- `self.view.frame` is (I assume) 0,0,320,380
- `myViewController.view` is a subview of `self.view`
- `myViewController.view.frame` is 320,0,320,480 *in `self.view`'s coordinate system*, so it's outside of its superview's frame (and off the right edge of the screen)

Now consider where the views are after the animations finish:

- `self.view.frame` is -320,0,320,480
- `myViewController.view` is still a subview of `self.view`
- `myViewController.view.frame` is 0,0,320,480 *in `self.view`'s coordinate system*, so it's fully inside its superview's frame, but its frame in screen coordinates is -320,0,320,480, so it is now entirely off the left edge of the screen

You need to make `myViewController.view` a sibling of `self.view`, not a subview.  Try this:

```
// Calculate the initial frame of myViewController.view to be
// the same size as self.view, but off the right edge of self.view.
// I don't like hardcoding coordinates...
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(frame);
myViewController.view.frame = frame;
[self.view.superview addSubview:myViewController.view];
// Now slide the views over.
[UIView animationWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    myViewController.view.frame = frame;
    frame.origin.x -= frame.size.width;
    self.view.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL done){
    [view1.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: "keep in mind that a navigation controller does _not_ slide the old view off the screen when a new view is pushed" Really?!

Comment: Oops.  I forgot how it actually looks. :)

Comment: thanks! Also how would I reverse this code for the animation going from View4 to View1?

Comment: Sorry I mean from myViewController to View1.

Comment: I actually figured it out but I am using coordinates which I do not want, can you show me how to do it without using coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell if you have other problems related to the context of where this code is called. Looks like `view1` is a UIViewController subclass. You should rename that, pretty confusing.

I did notice a problem with your frame manipulations. It looks like `self` is a container view controller, e.g. `self.view` contains the views being animated (`view1.view` and `myViewController.view` and shouldn't be animated itself. If that's correct your animation should be:

```
[self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
[myViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];    
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     [view1.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480)];
                     [myViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [view1.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

As an aside, it seems strange that a view controller would animate itself out of it's superview. If `self` is a container view controller I would expect the logic to be there. See my answer to [Animate change of view controllers without using navigation controller stack, subviews or modal controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su/8248284#8248284) for an example of how to implement a container view controller. It is trivial to modify my example there to do the slide in animation you want.