# How does View Controller Containment work in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5

In WWDC 2011 Session 102, Apple introduced View Controller Containment, which is the ability to create custom view controller containers, analogous to `UITabBarController`, `UINavigationController`, and the like.

I watched the examples several times. There are a flurry of methods associated with this pattern, but it was a little hard to figure them out exactly. I'm going to post here what I think is going on and see if the community will confirm or disconfirm my suspicions.

**Scenario 1: Moving from no parent to a new parent view controller**

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view]; // or something like this.
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Do the first two lines have to occur in the order given, or can they be reversed?

**Scenario 2: Moving from a parent view controller to no parent view controller**

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController];
```

Is it also necessary to call `[vc didMoveToParentViewController:nil]`? The examples in Session 102 *did not do this* in this scenario, but I don't know whether that was an omission or not.

**Scenario 3: Moving from one parent view controller to another**

This will likely occur in the following way, because the logic in each parent view controller will be encapsulated.

```
// In the old parent
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController];

// In the new parent
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**Questions**

My main question is this: Is this how view controller containment should work, in general? Are the mechanics given above correct?

Is it necessary to call `willMoveToParentViewController` before calling `addChildViewController`? This seems like the logical order to me, but is it strictly necessary?

Is it necessary to call `didMoveToParentViewController:nil` after calling `removeFromParentViewController`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `UIViewController` docs are pretty clear on when and when not to call `willMove`/`didMove` methods.  Check out the ["Implementing a Container View Controller"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) documentation.

The docs say, that if you do not override `addChildViewController`, you do not have to call  `willMoveToParentViewController:` method.  However you do need to call the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method after the transition is complete.  "Likewise, it is is the responsibility of the container view controller to call the `willMoveToParentViewController:` method before calling the `removeFromParentViewController` method. The `removeFromParentViewController` method calls the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller."

Also, there is an example worked out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su/8198515#8198515) and sample code [here](https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers).

Good Luck

Comment: I see, so `addChildViewController` should be balanced with `didMoveToParentViewController` and `willMoveToParentViewController` should be balanced with `removeFromParentViewController`. This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I missed it in the docs.

Comment: Why not? Why you do not have to call willMoveToParentViewController but hae to call didMoveToParentViewController?

Comment: Because that's what the docs say. Apple obviously feel we don't need to know.

Comment: The reason is for animation's sake: Say you're creating your own navigation controller. At the start of a slide-in animation, 'willMove' needs to be called, and at the end of the animation, 'didMove' needs to be called. Now when you call 'addChild' at the start of the animation, it automatically calls 'willMove' for you. But it can't know when the animation (if there is one) finishes, so you have to call 'didMove' manually at the end of animation (or immediately on no animation).

Comment: And as for a 'slide out' animation, eg the child is being removed, you have to call 'willMove' manually at the start of the animation, because uikit otherwise wouldn't know when to call your child VC's 'viewWillDisappear'. And at the end of the animation, when you call removeFromParentViewController, it can call 'didMove' automatically for you.

Answer (score 23):

This part is not correct:

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view]; // or something like this.
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

[According to the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:)

> When your custom container calls the addChildViewController: method, it automatically calls the willMoveToParentViewController: method of the view controller to be added as a child before adding it.

So you don't need the `[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self]` call. It is done automatically when you call `[self addChildViewController:vc]`. Here's the code sample again:

```
[self addChildViewController:vc];
// [vc willMoveToParentViewController:self] called automatically
[self.view addSubview:vc.view]; // or something like this.
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

[For removing view controllers:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didMoveToParentViewController:)

> The removeFromParentViewController method automatically calls the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller after it removes the child.

Presumably this call is `[oldVC didMoveToParentViewController:nil]`.

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController];
// [vc didMoveToParentViewController:nil] called automatically
```

Comment: it appears that if done otherwise, even if it seems to work, presentingViewController is not set on the presentedViewController.

Comment: Docs say call `didMoveToParentViewController`   "**immediately** after calling the addChildViewController: method", it does not specify when you actually add the child subview. I wonder if everyone has got this wrong.  Is there an example in some Apple Docs we can check this against?

Comment: Note: you *do* need to call `willMoveToParentViewController` prior to `addChildViewController` if the item you are moving is a custom class with overridden `addChildViewController` (unless your override calls it internally)