# How do I update a SwiftUI View that was embedded into UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

I'm looking for an equivalent of AppKit's [NSHostingView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingview) for UIKit so that I can embed a SwiftUI view in UIKit. Unfortunately, UIKit does not have an equivalent class to `NSHostingView`. The closest we have as an equivalent of [NSHostingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingcontroller), named [UIHostingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller). Since a view controller contains a view, we should be able to [call the appropriate UIViewController embedding methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24236625/35690), and then grab the `view` and use it directly.

[There](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/?time=452) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433826/include-swiftui-views-in-existing-uikit-application) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631892/addsubview-swiftui-view-to-uikit-uiview-in-swift) [articles](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-in-uikit/) that explain that this is *the way* to embed a SwiftUI view inside UIKit. However, they typically fall short in explaining how you would communicate from **UIKit ➡️ SwiftUI**. For example, imagine I implemented a SwiftUI view that acts as a progress bar, periodically, I'd like the progress to be updated. I want my legacy/UIKit code to update the SwiftUI view to display the new progress.

The [only article I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56827040/35690) that came close to explaining how to manipulate an embedded view's content suggested we do so by using `@ObservedObject`:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class CircleModel: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var text: String { didSet { didChange.send() } }

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

struct CircleView : View {
    @ObservedObject var model: CircleModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
            Text(model.text)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private weak var timer: Timer?
    private var model = CircleModel(text: "")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addCircleView()
        startTimer()
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    func addCircleView() {
        let circleView = CircleView(model: model)
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: circleView)
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            controller.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            controller.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func startTimer() {
        var index = 0
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            index += 1
            self?.model.text = "Tick \(index)"
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to make sense as the timer should trigger a chain of events that update the view:

1. ✅ `self?.model.text = "Tick 1"` (In `ViewController.startTimer()`).
2. ✅ `didChange.send()` (In `CircleModel.text.didSet`)
3. ❌ `Text(model.text)` (In `CircleView.body`)

As you can see by the indicators (which specify if something was run or not), the problem is that `didChange.send()` never triggers a re-run of `CircleView.body`.

How do I communicate from UIKit > SwiftUI to manipulate a SwiftUI view that was embedded in UIKit?

Comment: Your information is out of date. `ObservableObject` was changed (whilst iOS 13.0 was still in beta) to require an `objectWillChange` publisher instead of a `didChange` publisher. Asperi’s answer shows an easier way to implement your `ObservableObject`, by let it synthesize its own publisher from its `@Published` properties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need is to throw away that custom subject, and use standard `@Published`, as below

```
class CircleModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var text: String

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

**Tested on: Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2**

Comment: For anyone else who wonders how to get model.text as a binding for read/write access inside your SwiftUI view, but synchronizing it with the variable outside of SwiftUI, instead of model.text, it would just be $model.text since \@ObservableObject's wrapped value is a binding which can be used the same as a binding to a wrapped \@State property. No changes to your binding-based SwiftUI view code. (CircleModel would be declared with wrapper \@ObservedObject instead of \@State or instead of read-only normal property.) (Ignore \ characters.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I found both Asperi answer and Jared comment to work flawlessly.

Comment: Will share something that tripped me up. Only the `text` property on CircleModel has the `@Published` annotation, so you must update that property only in the view controller. Replacing the whole model, for example by writing `self?.model = CircleModel(text: "Tick \(index)")` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution that works for updates from SwiftUI view is.

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            hostingController.sizingOptions = .intrinsicContentSize
        } else {
       
        cancellable = state.objectWillChange
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                  self?.hostingController?.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            }
    }
        
        if let hostingView = hostingController.view {
            addSubview(hostingView)
            hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                hostingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                hostingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                hostingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                hostingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            ])
        }
        
        self.hostingController = hostingController
```

If you are updating view from UIKit and are resetting rootView then this approach seems to be sufficient

```
if let hostingController {
            hostingController.rootView = contentView
            hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        } else {
            let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            
            if let hostingView = hostingController.view {
                addSubview(hostingView)
                hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    hostingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                    hostingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                    hostingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                    hostingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
                ])
            }
            
            self.hostingController = hostingController
        }
```