# Muliple UINavigationViewController on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to build the the UI as shown in the MockUp.
For this I need to have two UINavigationViewControllers Side by Side inside a TabBarController. And on the left side I need a VerticalToolbar...

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks,
Stefan

[image: iPad MockUp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iOS ViewController Containment API's to achieve this.

Check 'Implementing a Container View Controller' topic in [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the same.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379759/how-does-view-controller-containment-work-in-ios-5/8379894#8379894) post.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a good article that points me to the correct use of UIViewController Containment :)

[Creating iPad Dashboard Using UIViewController Containment](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/848_Creating_iPad_Dashboard_Using_UIViewController_Containment.aspx)