# Container View Controllers - notify parent of action

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

Say I have a custom container view controller (MainViewController) where I do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        

    HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:homeVC];
    [self.view addSubview:homeVC.view];

}
```

The HomeViewController will have a button, such as "go", that when pressed will need to advance to the next view controller. So I need to notify the MainViewController of this action. What is the best way to do this?

I'm using a custom container because I need to do custom transitions between the view controllers. When "go" is pressed, some of the views on the HomeViewController will animate while the views from the new view controller are animating into place.

Obviously I could give the HomeViewController a property of type MainViewController and make calls that way, but I'm hoping that there is a cleaner way with the container view controller API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either use delegate or block;

**Using delegate**

Create a protocol :

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)someAction; 
@end
```

Just declare a delegate in HomeViewController.h like this:

```
id<SomeProtocol> delegate;
```

and then in MainViewController's viewDidLoad set it like this:

```
homeVC.delegate = self;
//some where in MainViewController implement the protocol method
-(void)someAction
{
    //do something
}
```

then when you press the button in homeVC, just simply call:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someAction)]) {
    [self.delegate someAction];
}
```

**Using Block**:

In HomeViewController.h declare a block property:

```
typedef void (^ActionBlock)();

@property (nonatomic, copy) ActionBlock block;
```

then in MainViewController ViewDidLoad:

```
homeVC.block = ^(){
    //do something
};
```

then when you press the button in homeVC, just simply call:

```
self.block();
```

Comment: ok, so there's nothing I can leverage from the UIViewController Containment API?

Comment: Not quite sure bu this post might help [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379759/how-does-view-controller-containment-work-in-ios-5)

Comment: I'd +1 this 3 times over if I could. Not only did it answer the same question for me but it advanced my understanding of blocks tenfold :)

Comment: The `typedef` declaration the block needs a type like...
`typedef void (^ActionBlock)();`

Comment: @EricQian I am getting bad access error when I implement the block to handle child view's action. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490095/handle-containerviewcontrollers-action-in-parentviewcontroller) could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 10):

There's another way too...
Every view controller has a `parentViewController` property so using that you can do this...

In `MainViewController` define a method for the action you want to perform...

```
- (void)someMethod:(BOOL)someParam;
```

Then in `HomeViewController` you can do...

```
MainViewController* parent = (MainViewController*)[self parentViewController];
[parent someMethod:paramValue];
```

HTH :)

Comment: Good quick and dirty way here.  Use the selected answer if you have a little more time to craft the protocol.  Thanks pedro!

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common pattern. The parent will be the actual instance that will handle the action, by providing a `protocol` and a [default extension](http://samwize.com/2016/10/24/swift-protocol-development-guide/).

In Swift 3:

Parent view controller:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func foo()
}

extension ParentViewController: SomeProtocol {
    func foo() {
        // Parent handles it
    }
}
```

Child view controller:

```
 @IBAction func tapGo(_ sender: Any) {
    (parent as? SomeProtocol)?.foo()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was just what I was looking for :)