# Detect segue inside container

Tags: ios

When you have an embedded view controller inside a container, how can you detect when it is about to perform a segue?

For example:

[image: Storyboard]

I want to detect when a segue happens within the embedded view controller from the view controller containing the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the segue management is done by the embedded view controller, a solution would be to establish a delegate mechanism between your embedded view controller and the containing view controller, so that the containing view controller is informed if a segue is performed.

If you don't want your view controllers know each other, you could also send notifications through the `NSNotificationCenter` from the `prepareForSegue` method and react to them in the containing view controller.

Comment: After a bit of debugging I found that (as my app is all based on navigation controllers) the notification `UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification` was sent each time, so I added an observer for it. I am picking your answer as mentioning notifications got me thinking, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the embedded view you can use the `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method to notify the container view. I assume that the segues have attached an indentifier in storyboard.

Comment: What I mean is to detect it in the view controller that has the container

Comment: As @Christian says in his answer you will have to use a notification or a delegate. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968321/container-view-controllers-notify-parent-of-action