# Add ViewController as subView and showing message sent to deallocated instance 0x8a6efc0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I Have `ViewController` with `UIButton`

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    FirstTopViewController *controller = [[FirstTopViewController alloc]init];
    controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Upper"];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(300,0, 320, 460);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 320, 460);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
      [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

As here i add newViewController as subView of `MenuViewController`.

On `FirstViewController` with `UIButton`

```
- (IBAction)backToMain:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                          delay:0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
```

`ISSUE`
When i pressed button on `MenuViewController` it present new `FirstViewController` as subView with animation perfectly but when i pressed Button on `FirstViewController` it is Crashing with

```
-[FirstViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8a6efc0
```

Please review.

Comment: Try to declare "FirstTopViewController *controller" variable as ivar instead of local variable and check..:-)

Comment: Use [viewController containment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379759/how-does-view-controller-containment-work-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `FirstTopViewController *controller` as class level variable. Problem is controller object is local and gets deallocated after that btn_funtion is done. Then when you tap button it sends message to a deallocated instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of FirstViewController in MenuViewController's .h file.
And now your FirstViewController's instace will be hold by parentview.