# How to switch between two view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, switching

I have two `UIViewControllers`, vc1 and vc2.

I want to switch between them. But before loading the view of the new view controller, I want to destroy/release/remove (I'm not sure abt the correct word to use here) the previous viewcontroller.

For example, when I am switching to vc2 from vc1 ,I want to destroy vc1 completely, so that when I return to vc1 from vc2, vc1 will be loaded from scratch (i.e. `viewDidLoad` will be executed).

Which type of view switching should I opt for?

1. presentModal...
2. addSubview.

I am not using a navigation controller.

Currently I am using the presentModal... method, but when I use `dismissModalViewcontroller` on the newly presented view controller, it doesn't show up a new instance of the previous view controller. Instead, it shows the already running instance of it.

I want the `viewDidLoad` method of the previous view controller to run when I dismiss the newly presented view controller.

Comment: You should use the delegate method that you (should) use to dismiss the modalVC to call the new data for your previousVC.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly needs to happen in `viewDidLoad`?

You also have `viewWillAppear` available to you, so it could be that you could move the required functionality there and still use the modal presentation.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer. You can do this with or without animation.

[Animate change of view controllers without using navigation controller stack, subviews or modal controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su/8248284#8248284)