# Swapping rootViewController with animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a little trouble swapping rootViewControllers with animation. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    } completion:nil];
```

It kind of works except that right before the animation, the screen turns to black and then the animation occurs. It looks like the original rootViewController is getting removed right before the animation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`transitionWithView` is intended to animate subviews of the specified container view. It is not so simple to animate changing the root view controller. I've spent a long time trying to do it w/o side effects. See:

[Animate change of view controllers without using navigation controller stack, subviews or modal controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su/8248284#8248284)

EDIT: added excerpt from referenced answer

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                    toView:viewController.view
                  duration:0.65f
                   options:transition
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
                }];
```

Comment: It's working fine in other parts of my app. I tried using your code, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'it's working fine in other parts...'. The exact same code is? Also, not sure which part of my code you tried. I added the relevant piece to the answer.

Comment: I just tried what you posted and now the view changes right before the animation actually occurs.

Comment: you must be doing something after this that is causing the problem. post the rest of your code after the animation. in general, you need to wait for the animation to complete before making other view changes. this code is correct.

Comment: Yeah that's probably it. I just decided to restructure the app a lithe bit so this will not be an issue. I'm marking this as accepted because it seems to be the correct solution to the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: well, thanks. the acceptance is nice but I hope you resolve the issue. if you move any post-animation view changes into the completion block, that should help.

Comment: I think I do have it resolved. I decided that it would be okay to just modally present the view. It seems to be working pretty nicely.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked properly for me with iOS 6.

Answer (score 45):

I am aware this is a quite old question, however, neither the accepted answer nor the alternatives provided a good solution (when the animation finished the navigation bar of the new root view controller blinked from white to the background color, which is very jarring).

I fixed this by snapshotting the last screen of the first view controller, overlaying it over the second (destination) view controller, and then animating it as I wanted **after** I set the second view controller as root:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
[self.destinationViewController.view addSubview:overlayView];
self.window.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    overlayView.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [overlayView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

**EDIT:** Swift 3 version of the code:

```
let overlayView = UIScreen.main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
destinationViewController.view.addSubview(overlayView)
window.rootViewController = destinationViewController

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    overlayView.alpha = 0
}, completion: { finished in
    overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

Comment: I tried a bunch of the other solutions, and this is the smoothest animation I found. I also like the simplicity of the approach.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. This is the best replacement for UIView.transitionFromView I've ever found

Comment: Thanks mate! Easy and subtle!

Answer (score 5):

I have found [transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW112) to produce a more reliable result.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:window
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    [fromView removeFromSuperview];
                    [window addSubview:toView];
                    window.rootViewController = toViewController;
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

If you leave it until the completion block to set the root view controller then during methods such as view(Will/Did)Appear

```
self.view.window.rootViewController
```

Will still be set to the previous view controller.  This may not be a problem in most situations unless you need to pass on that reference to the rootViewController to other code during those methods as I did.

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted answer (at the time of writing this answer) isn't ideal because it might not position UI elements like the navigation bar correctly during the animation or lead to other **layout glitches** as described in [Marko Nikolovski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29235480/2062785). However, pushing a *snapshot* of the current view controller's view on top of the next view controller's view for animation purposes isn't ideal either because it cannot be used for view controllers in which any kind of animation is happening during the transition to the next view controller as a snapshot is just a **static image**.

Taking [cclogg's basic idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832157/2062785) here's my implementation for a smooth transition between two view controllers that doesn't bother about alpha values:

```
/// Replaces the window's current `rootViewController` with the `newViewController` 
/// passed as a parameter. If `animated`, the window animates the replacement 
/// with a cross dissolve transition.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - newViewController: The view controller that replaces the current view controller.
///   - animated: Specifies if the transition between the two view controllers is animated.
///   - duration: The transition's duration. (Ignored if `animated == false`)
private func swapCurrentViewController(with newViewController: UIViewController, 
                                       animated: Bool = true, 
                                       duration: TimeInterval = 1) {

    // Get a reference to the window's current `rootViewController` (the "old" one)
    let oldViewController = window?.rootViewController

    // Replace the window's `rootViewController` with the new one
    window?.rootViewController = newViewController

    if animated, let oldView = oldViewController?.view {

        // Add the old view controller's view on top of the new `rootViewController`
        newViewController.view.addSubview(oldView)

        // Remove the old view controller's view in an animated fashion
        UIView.transition(with: window!,
                          duration: duration,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { oldView.removeFromSuperview() },
                          completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It's important to replace the window's `rootViewController` *before* initiating the transition or animation because that's how the new view controller gets to know its context, i.e. the correct layout margins etc.

---

This is a way to go if you **really need to replace the window's `rootViewController`** for whatever reason. However, I want to point out that from an architectural point of view a far better approach in my opinion is to create a view controller that's solely responsible for handling transitions between the two other view controllers and set that one as the window's `rootViewController` and then **never change it**. It's well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248284/2062785) to a similar question.

Comment: This answer deserved more upvotes :D Works like a charm, and solves the glitch, where the window will kinda animate from the top left corner and down, instead of crossdissolving. If I could upvote more than once, I would have done it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was a slight modification of Marko Nikolovski's answer. My existing root view controller had an animated spinner on it, so a snapshot looked weird because it froze the animation. In the end, I was able to do the following (inside the current root view controller):

```
NextRootViewController *nextRootVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextRootViewController"];

self.view.window.rootViewController = nextRootVC;

[nextRootVC addSubview:self.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    self.view.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: I liked your idea!

Answer (score 1):

From ViewController

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    
let transition = CATransition()
transition.type = .push
transition.subtype = .fromRight
    
let window = self.view.window
window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
window?.rootViewController = vc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of swapping rootViewControllers, why don't you create either a custom View, or maybe just a UINavigationController (don't show titlebar) and put the "rootViews" you want to swap between under that.

Comment: I'll consider this as a last resort. I'm looking for a slightly more elegant method.

Comment: @edc1591 maybe (just a guess) the most elegant solution would be a custom "SwapViewController" that performs the animated transition for you.

Comment: Maybe he is referencing window.rootViewController somewhere from the app later, that's why you may want to keep a vc rvc.