# Replace window.rootViewController with animation works partially

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to replace the window rootViewController with animation and it only works partially.

I create a UINavigationController programatically -

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"InboxStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *innerViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerView"];
UINavigationController *centerView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:innerViewController];
```

Afterwards I replace the window root view controller wrapped in an animation block -

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.viewController.view.window
                  duration:0.5
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    self.viewController.view.window.rootViewController = centerView;
                }
                completion:nil];
```

What happens is that the animation happen but the controller that I create is only partially visible, take a look at the following picture -

[image]
 [image]

So as you can see during the rotation the view is only partially rendered.

Anyone bumped into this kind of behaviour before?

Comment: a bug? delete the app on simulator and run it again.

Comment: What is self in the code you posted? It's not clear what class you're executing this code in.

Comment: self is some NSObject another UIViewController have.
The flow is - 
Instantiate my object in some other UIViewController, use the object to replace the root view controller with another one.

AFAIK this is pretty standard flow, still no idea why it's partially rendered. Also if I don't use animation and just replace the root view it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So after a *long* search I found the problem was in the `[UIView transitionWithView:...]`
Searching a bit more in stackoverflow I found [Swapping rootViewController with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827891/swapping-rootviewcontroller-with-animation)

Using `[UIView transitionFromView:..]` works perfectly.

The new code -

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                    toView:self.centerViewController.view
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
                {
                    self.window.rootViewController = self.centerViewController;
                }];
```

Comment: Is this code really working?? This should not work because this will give compile time warning... you are assigning UIView to rootViewController property... which is wrong... Please correct your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Auto layout?  If so, try disabling it.  I have run into multiple problems with auto layout and animations.