# Objective-C : Modal Segues and Releasing View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

The initial view controller on my app is a UITabBarController that displays for logged in users.

For new users, however, my app delegate will point them to a login/registration view controller first:

```
// New user, show login
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
```

When the user has completed the login/registration, I then send the user to the tabbar as such:

```
// Login done, go to main view
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userLoginToMainSeg" sender:self];
```

However, doing it this way, the LoginViewController is not released (dealloc is not called).

Can someone explain the error in my logic here?

Comment: What kind of segue is `userLoginToMainSeg ` ?

Comment: @TamásZahola it's a modal segue

Answer (score 0):

Your modal segue is basically doing:

```
[loginViewController presentViewController:mainViewController animated:YES completion: ...];
```

What this means is that `mainViewController` becomes `loginViewController`s `presentedViewController`:

```
loginViewController.presentedViewController == mainViewController
mainViewController.presentingViewController == loginViewController
```

When you're [presenting a view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html), the presenting view controller remains in the view controller hierarchy, so that you can later navigate back by calling:

```
[loginViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: ...];
```

So it's perfectly normal that `loginViewController` is not released, since it's still the window's `rootViewController`. It's only that `loginViewController` is obstructed by the presented `mainViewController`.

If you want to eradicate `loginViewController` you can set `window.rootViewController` directly, but that wouldn't animate the transition. You can achieve animation [by messing around the view controllers' views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827891/swapping-rootviewcontroller-with-animation), but it's kind of outside the officially sanctioned territory...

IMO the cleanest solution would be to implement a basic [container view controller](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/) that would be your window's `rootViewController`, and that could orchestrate the transition between `loginViewController` and `mainViewController` by animating their views, and then throwing away `loginViewController`. It would be kind of a primitive navigation controller without a navigation bar and a navigation stack – just swapping the current view controller with the new one, and throwing away the former.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a way to release the loginviewcontroller after I present the tabbarcontroller? Would setting the tabbarcontroller as the rootviewcontroller do the trick?

Comment: It would do, but wouldn't animate. I've updated the answer with some possible solutions.