# UIButton click crashes app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uibutton, catransition

I have button on `page 1` when i click on button i am performing some animation and navigation to new page say `Page 2`.

On `page 2` there is cancel button when i click on that i want to go back to my previuos page i.e `Page 1` but on click of cancel button my app crashes.

Here is my sample code on `Page 1:`**Name of page CRViewController**

```
- (IBAction)ClickMe:(id)sender {
    RegistraionViewController *secondController = [[RegistraionViewController alloc] init];

    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:@"push"];
    [transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
}
```

Code which is on `Page 2:` **Name of page RegistraionViewController** (on Which crashes on click.)

```
- (IBAction)Click:(id)sender {
    CRViewController *secondController = [[CRViewController alloc] init];

    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:@"push"];
    [transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
}
```

Comment: And when the app crashes, is there any error message?

Comment: @Krunal: Show How you create the Cancel button.

Comment: No it shows only `lldb` in my log

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the button action. Then execute it line by line and see what line it crashes on.

Comment: @Krunal: [self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; instead of this use [self presentViewController:secondController animated:YES];

Comment: @Krunal : Are you try above that

Comment: Just don't use [self.view addSubview: .....] and your code run perfectly..

Comment: @Jageen: when i remove  `[self.view addSubview: .....]` animation comes but after animation it loads same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)ClickMe:(id)sender {   
    RegistraionViewController *secondController = [[RegistraionViewController alloc] init];   
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];   
}


- (IBAction) Click:(id)sender {    
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```

**Edit:**
I'm sorry. If you want custom some  UIViewController transitions animation, see below:
[UIViewController transition - objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363337/uiviewcontroller-transition-objective-c)
http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/
Or you can try this:

```
- (IBAction)ClickMe:(id)sender {
    RegistraionViewController *secondController = [[RegistraionViewController alloc] init];

    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:@"push"];
    [transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:NO]; 
}

- (IBAction)Click:(id)sender {
    CRViewController *secondController = [[CRViewController alloc] init];

    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:@"push"];
    [transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:secondController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I want some animation. not push and pop

Comment: I have tried this code, it work. You should ensure you have navigationController in your controller hierarchy.

Comment: animation comes but after animation it loads same file

Comment: Here is my code:https://www.dropbox.com/s/tmh8ik23t54w63g/TestTransitionAnimation.zip

Comment: All file are lost in your provide project.

Comment: screenshot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueg2konzx9i38vi/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-30%20at%207.17.10%20PM.png

Comment: I am sorry to keep you waiting. Here is code:https://www.dropbox.com/s/lifw5z5cqrubdm7/ABCD.zip

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is lying somewhere because of the subview. I have tried your code.

I did the following code in my project with some animation hope it helps you.

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
    [animation setDuration:0.8];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionMoveIn];

    //[[self.view layer]addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fview"];

    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView animated:NO];
```

In animation type you can give whichever animation you want.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Unable to see animation :(

Comment: I am running this code in my project right now man. Check it if you have pass the correct view name in it. In your code if you push the view rather than subviewing it it is showing you animation.

Comment: `RegistraionViewController *secondController = [[RegistraionViewController alloc] init];CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];[animation setDelegate:self];[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];[animation setDuration:0.8];[animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionMoveIn];
  [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:NO];`

Comment: I tried above code, animation comes but after animation it loads same file.

Comment: Then check if you are passing a view onto which you want to nevigate. And don't take same names for the object of different view controllers.

Comment: I tried just now. It is working man. You would have done some mistake.

Comment: If i simply write: `RegistraionViewController *secondController = [[RegistraionViewController alloc] init];   
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];` still i am unable to navigate to new page

Comment: It is not opening. Did you put breakpoint and check that if it goes in your method? and try to give name of your xib with initwithnibname and check.

Comment: You can tell me in chat and write your code and i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

*

```
- (IBAction)ClickMe:(id)sender {
    RegistraionViewController *secondController = [[RegistraionViewController alloc] init];
    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:@"push"];
    [transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [self addChildViewController:secondController];
    [self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
}
```

*
replace your sample code on Page 1: with the above and then check.

Hope this helps to you