# UIView transitions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, transition

I am using ViewControllers for my different views, this is currently how I am switching from page to page:

```
- (IBAction)switchToSecondPage:(id)sender 
{
    SecondPage * secondPage = [[SecondPage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController: secondPage animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This is the typical new view coming up from the bottom of the screen. I can use this to change the transition style, but I only get a couple choices to chose from, and none of them are any good.

```
secondPage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

I am looking for transitions that are similar to the original one you get (page slides up from bottom). So I want 'slides down from top'  and 'slides from left/right'. Is there any way I can do this. I see all sorts of applications doing this but I haven't been successful in finding anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is,

```
  [self.view addSubview:secondPage.view];
  secondPage.view.frame = frameOutSideCurrentView;//Frame is set as outside the screen
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{
                         //actual frame needed with an animation.
                         secondPage.view.frame = originalFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                        //if you need to anything specific once the animation is completed.
                     }];
```

Another way to do is by [using this](https://gist.github.com/1394947). `TransitionController` is custom implementation which helps to do this. In case you are facing issue with above code, use the category methods in this implementation. There are methods such as,

```
- (id)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                     withOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options;
```

which can be used to achieve this.

Comment: What do I put into frameOutsideCurrentView and originalFrame, everything i've tried gives errors.

Comment: For frameOutsideCurrentView, set a frame which is outside the current screen frame as CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480); and while animating set originalFrame as CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); This should animate from left to right.

Comment: The simulator runs but when I click the button nothing happens. Also, isn't this just using the same view? My second page opens a completely different UIViewController view.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check if the frame is set properly. Or else I would suggest you to use https://gist.github.com/1394947. Check this for how to use that, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8248284/1730272

Comment: Wow thank you very much! It works perfectly, the only problem is that nothing on the second page works. If I click a button the simulator crashes and xcode will be highlighting "0x10dd09b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi"

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it with adding "
    [self presentViewController: new animated:YES completion:NULL];" after completion:^(BOOL finished) {

Comment: @SinaYamani, If you are facing issues with that, try using TransitionController which I mentioned as second option.

Comment: The way I solved this problem causes further problems, it works fine for the first transition, but the second one automatically crashes. If I remove the code from after completion, I cannot interact with the new view. I will try using the TransitionController method now.

Comment: @SinaYamani, That is because your secondPage is getting released. You might have to declare it as `@property` and use it as self.secondPage instead of just secondPage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19271/discussion-between-sina-yamani-and-acb)