# if statement pushing to viewController on els not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement

I made a if statement here where if the textfield contains less then 4 symbols it gives an popup. if the text field is contains more then 4 it should push to a different viewcontroller.

For some reason the push is not working. the pop-up works fine.

Basically the viewcontroller we are on right now is a "first time launch setup page" so I don't want the user to navigate back to it. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)initialButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"initialButton clicked");

     if([userEmail.text length] <4)
     {
         [WCAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Email is empty" message:@"You haven't entered an email yet. Please enter one so we can /sent you the shipping labels."     customizationBlock:^(WCAlertView *alertView) {
             alertView.style = WCAlertViewStyleBlackHatched;
         } completionBlock:^(NSUInteger buttonIndex, WCAlertView *alertView) {
             if (buttonIndex == 0) {
                 NSLog(@"Cancel");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Ok");
             }
         } cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
     }
     else {
              ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
              [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to push a viewController that is tied to a XIB? If so you're going to need to use: ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXIBName" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your view controller embedded inside a navigation controller? (if not `self.navigationController` will be `nil`)

If not you need to init a UINavigationController with your view controller.

```
UINavigationController *navCon = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
```

And then set it to be your window's rootViewController.

Comment: ah wait a sec navigationcontroller is creating a navbar. Basicly the viewcontroller we are on right now is a "first time launch setup page" so i dont want the user to navigate back to it. how can i do that?

Comment: You can remove the left "back" button from the nav bar.

Comment: fixed it by using this transitionController:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su