# transition between ViewControllers not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

So I got this button that with a `if` statement that pushes to a the `StartViewController`. I made a `NSLog@"transition successful"` in the `viewDidLoad` of this viewcontroller to check if the transition is made.

In the log its showing the transition successful but on the screen not transition is made.

Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)initialButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"initialButton clicked");

   if([userEmail.text length] <4)
   {
       [WCAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Email is empty" message:@"You haven't entered an email yet. Please enter one so we can sent you the shipping labels." customizationBlock:^(WCAlertView *alertView) {
           alertView.style = WCAlertViewStyleBlackHatched;
       } completionBlock:^(NSUInteger buttonIndex, WCAlertView *alertView) {
           if (buttonIndex == 0) {
               NSLog(@"Cancel");
           } else {
               NSLog(@"Ok");
           }
       } cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
   }
   else
   {

       StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
       self.transitionController = [[[TransitionController alloc] initWithViewController:startViewController] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil];
       [initialViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
       self.window.rootViewController = self.startViewController;

   }


}
```

and here is the log:

```
2012-12-14 09:22:55.431 Janssenpakketapp[24165:c07] initialViewController loaded
2012-12-14 09:23:04.021 Janssenpakketapp[24165:c07] initialButton clicked
2012-12-14 09:23:06.116 Janssenpakketapp[24165:c07] Ok
2012-12-14 09:23:11.909 Janssenpakketapp[24165:c07] initialButton clicked
2012-12-14 09:23:11.911 Janssenpakketapp[24165:c07] transition succesful
```

Comment: U r initializing the instance & then removing that view, so I think thats why its printing `NSLog` but not showing you anything on screen! I dnt understand why did u used `removeFromSupreView` & then assignment of its instance to `rootViewController`? Can u explain?

Comment: oh my mistake startViewController should be InitialViewController. Thats the viewcontroller we are in right now. But its still not working if i remove that part.

Comment: How can i release the current viewcontroller?

Comment: If you use a UINavigationController you don't have to or want to. Just push a new view onto it. If you want a new UINavigationController I would still not release the old one, since it doesn't take much space and it is easy to switch back to when needed

Comment: got it working!

StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
       AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
       [appDelegate.transitionController transitionToViewController:startViewController withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight];

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New update: this should work:

```
StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.transitionController transitionToViewController:startViewController withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight];
```

Comment: oh my mistake startViewController should be InitialViewController. Thats the viewcontroller we are in right now. But its still not working if i remove that part.

Comment: i get this error if i try this:
/Users/florianschaal/Developer/Janssenpakketapp/Janssenpakketapp/InitialViewController.m:48:54: No visible @interface for 'TransitionController' declares the selector 'initWithRootViewController:'

Comment: Then TransitionController is not a UINavigationController. What is it and what is it used for?

Comment: its used as UIViewController if im correct. Pick this one up from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su

sorry kinda beginning IOS programming :P

Comment: Are you using some kind of special transition animation?

Comment: im using UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight

Comment: got it working!

StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
       AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
       [appDelegate.transitionController transitionToViewController:startViewController withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight];

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Haha I just wrote the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

you want to to add transition animation then use bellow code...

```
    StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.startViewController;
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
```