# Toggle Two Views With Same Data

Tags: ios

I have some data that I want to switch between a table view and a map view. In the past I have just put everything onto one view controller. But I think this will get really messy because I will have many subviews for two separate views all on one view controller. So I would have to hide one view to edit the other. (Unless this is normal?)

I think my preferred option would be one view controller with 2 subviews, and here is what I have thought about so far...

1. I tried using a view container, which separates out a `UIView` with an embedded segue, but it seems as though it can only have one segue connected to it, and I needed two (for table and map). It was hard to find good example material using this view container.
2. I then thought about using nibs. I started IOS programming after storyboards, so I have never used nibs, yet, but this might be a good situation? Make two `UIView` nibs that can be loaded into the view controller.
3. I could just use my one view controller, make two views inside it, one that holds all the table view subviews, and one that holds all the map view subviews. Like I said, though, this makes editing the view tougher.

So my question, what is a good way to create a view that uses the same data, but can toggle views without making the storyboard view controller bloated?

I thought about popping and pushing on the navigation stack as well to 'toggle' the views, but I think the views are on the same level, and the navigation stack doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this as a guide to do exactly what you're suggesting:

[Animate change of view controllers without using navigation controller stack, subviews or modal controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su)

I have a main `UIViewController` and two other `UIViewControllers` created on my storyboard. I get one of the controllers from the storyboard, and transition the view to it and back. I don't have my code in front of me right now, so if this doesn't immediately help you I'll edit this post and put my code in later this evening.

Comment: I am looking into it and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, used timthetoolman's answer and that did what I needed.