# touchesbegan doesn't work on subview from second viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, touchesbegan

I'm developing an iPhone app and I am trying to solve the following problem. In my main viewcontroller view I add the view of an other viewcontroller as subview. But the touchesbegan function of the other viewcontroller doesn't respond to the touches. What is the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the subview a UIImageView? Then you have to set `userInteractionEnabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing this but adding views of one controller as a subview is another has been discouraged since iOS 5. In iOS 5 you can contain `UIViewController`s within each other using the `addChildViewController` method. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198515/442328) provides a bit insight into the matter.

**Update**
[Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) on containment.