# Best way to transition to different views when all views link to each other in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple iPad app that consists of 5 different View Controllers. Each one has links to every other one. The user starts off on the main page, selects one of the 4 other pages, and from those pages, can go back to the main page or directly to any other page. What is the best way to do that?

I could use modal segues, but I could then end up with huge chains of modal views. I don't know if there are any memory issues with this, but from what I've read, this isn't really what modal segues are for. I was considering using modal segues, but dismissing each modal view before displaying the next.

A Navigator Controller seems to be designed more for a hierarchy of views, not views that have no relationship to each other.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can have a tabbar or a custom side bar?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Split or https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Sidebar

Comment: Thanks, but tab bar or side bar or split views don't work in to the design. The ultimate question is: when the design is set, and the look and feel of the app is more like a web page, where the user can jump around at will between the various pages, what is the best way to get around?

Answer (score 0):

Using UITabBar is a good solution. You can place your 4 ViewControllers in a UITabBarController. And from your MainViewCOntroller you can launch it like this

```
UITabBarController *controller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    controller.viewControllers = @[vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4];
    NSArray *items = controller.tabBar.items ;
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *item4 = [items objectAtIndex:3];

    item1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image for vc1"];
    item2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image for vc2"];
    item3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image for vc3"];
    item4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image for vc4"];

    item1.title = @"Title1" ;
    item2.title = @"Title2" ;
    item3.title = @"Title3"  ;
    item4.title = @"Title4" ;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Now , you also need to swich between any viewControllers or MainViewController as well. You can go back to MainViewController by pressing navigation Back button. And of course there will be some events when you switch to another ViewController within the TabBar. To do that you can use this,

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2 ; // To select ViewController 3 from any of VC1 , VC2 , VC4
```

Comment: The design has already been done and approved by the client and a UITabBar and Back button are not part of it. Maybe I can use this general solution without actually displaying a tab bar with a back button. I've run into this before, where I've had situations where the user can jump around between various pages, without always a nice trail that can be unwound. I've always wondered how best to deal with these situations. In all cases, the design doesn't allow for your typical iPad controls (such as a Tab Bar), at least not visually. I will investigate this more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer in UIViewController as shown in this link: [Animate change of view controllers without using navigation controller stack, subviews or modal controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146253/animate-change-of-view-controllers-without-using-navigation-controller-stack-su/8198515#8198515)

Thanks to everyone that responded.