# Present and dismiss last UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app to present `UIViewController` and dismiss the current `UIViewController` at the same time.

Currently I'm in `viewcontroller1` and i want to present `viewcontroller2` as main controller and dismiss `viewcontroller1` to remove it from memory, so `viewcontroller2` will be the main controller after presenting and there is no `viewcontroller1` in stack.

I've tried :

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controller2") as! viewcontroller2
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in

    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

But it gave me : `0x7fee28711900> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Is there is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a `UIViewController` entirely, you should do this:

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = newController
```

This however will not cross-dissolve.

If you *need* to cross, you'll just have to present the new view controller "over" the old one, or follow the advice in this post and re-write it Swift:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248284/233602

Comment: where do i do that ? in viewDidLoad of second presented controller ? so by applying your code it will dismiss the old view controller from memory ?

Comment: I would recommend you centralise your logic for presenting view controllers - perhaps in your app delegate, or better, in a dedicated controller class, and put the above code in there.

Comment: Updated answer with a link to a post showing you how to animate.